# Accessing index value of a table element in angular

Tags: html, angular

so i have a table right here. Each row contains a name, id, status and edit (Delete Button, Terminate and so on).
Now i need to delete the element of the table once you click the delete button. Once clicked, it'll open up a modal which asks if the user really wants to delete user xyz. I'm having a hard time achieving the ID where the button is clicked. For Example:

```
Name    ID     Status        Edit
Steven  1     Terminated     Delete
```

If you click the Delete button, the modal opens.
"Do you really want to delete user **1**?

But I dont know how to get the value, depending on where the click happened.
My code is the following (just a small snippet of the modal):

```
<div *ngIf="showDeleteModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal__wrapper">
    <h1 class="modal__title">
      {{ 'TENANT_CONFIRM_DELETE' | translate: { tenantId: users[0].tenant_id } }}
    </h1>
    <div class="modal__close" (click)="showDeleteModal2 = false"></div>
    <div class="modal__content">
      Type <b>"Yes"</b> if you really want to delete. <br />
```

```
<button *ngIf="tenant.accountStatus == 'TERMINATED'" id="tenant-list-delete-{{ tenant.tenant_id }}"
                class="btn" (click)="deleteTenantUser = tenant;                           showDeleteModal2 = true">
                {{ 'USER_DELETE_BUTTON' | translate }}
</button>
```

And this is where the table is created:

```
<tr id="tenant-list" *ngFor="let tenant of users; index as i">
            <td>{{ tenant.tenant_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ tenant.tenant_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ tenant.accountStatus}}</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the backend sends an array of users, which have a property like tenant_id, tenant_name and accountStatus. I hardcoded the ID currently as you can see in the first code snippet ( tenantId: users[0].tenant_id). What can i do to exchange the 0 and get the Id?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Call a function and remove it from the users array?

```
<tr id="tenant-list" *ngFor="let tenant of users; index as i">
   <td>{{ tenant.tenant_id }}</td>
   <td>{{ tenant.tenant_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ tenant.accountStatus}}</td>
   <td> <button *ngIf="tenant.accountStatus == 'TERMINATED'" class="btn" 
         (click)="deleteTenantUser(i)">
         {{ 'USER_DELETE_BUTTON' | translate }}
        </button>
   </td>
</tr>




 //function
deleteTenentUser(index):void{
    this.users.splice(index,1);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out and tell you how it worked.